# Allowed to start href with a number?

Tags: html, css

I've got a website with a seat selection that uses `<a href="#A1">A1</a>` for each seat and then has an onclick event in js which takes the href of that  and does something with it. My question is: am I allowed to call it `href="#1A"` even though it starts with a number? It isn't related at all to an id or class, I'm only using it to identify the seat the user is clicking on, but I'm not sure if starting with a number causes any issues I don't know about.

Comment: Did you atleast tried  `starting with a number`? You will get to know, if it works then no issue or else there is some issue

Comment: yeah I did try it and it works but that doesn't mean it's not going to cause issues that I don't know about with browser compatibility or accessibility or something like that that I'm not aware of.

Comment: As far I know, it won't cause any issue. There is no harm using numbers in href.